# The best way for designing many to many entities relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have two tables permissions and groups of many to many relationship

```
CREATE TABLE `permissions` (
 `Permission_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Permission_Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Permission_Id`)
)
```

Groups table

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
 `Group_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Group_Desc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Group_Id`)
)
```

I am confuse how to implement the many to many relationship

which is better to create a composite primary key of Group_id and Permission_id in a new table

Or to create a new table & select the columns from the two table using join keyword  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the solution.

I need a to create "junction" table to hold many-to-many relationship in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE Groups_Permissions
(
Group_Id INT,
Permission_Id INT,
)
```

The combination of Group_Id  and Permmission_Id  should be UNIQUE and have FK to groups and permission tables.

Answer (score 1):

From [*my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table):

Do it this way.

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

```
⚈  Lack of an AUTO_INCREMENT id for this table -- The PK given is the 'natural' PK; there is no good reason for a surrogate.
⚈  "MEDIUMINT" -- This is a reminder that all INTs should be made as small as is safe (smaller ⇒ faster). Of course the declaration here must match the definition in the table being linked to.
⚈  "UNSIGNED" -- Nearly all INTs may as well be declared non-negative
⚈  "NOT NULL" -- Well, that's true, isn't it?
⚈  "InnoDB" -- More effecient than MyISAM because of the way the PRIMARY KEY is clustered with the data in InnoDB.
⚈  "INDEX(y_id, x_id)" -- The PRIMARY KEY makes it efficient to go one direction; this index makes the other direction efficient. No need to say UNIQUE; that would be extra effort on INSERTs.
⚈  In the secondary index, saying just INDEX(y_id) would work because it would implicit include x_id. But I would rather make it more obvious that I am hoping for a 'covering' index.
```

To conditionally INSERT new links, use IODKU

Note that if you had an AUTO_INCREMENT in this table, IODKU would "burn" ids quite rapidly.

**More**

A `FOREIGN KEY` implicitly creates an index on the column(s) involved.

`PRIMARY KEY(a,b)` (1) says that the combo `(a,b)` is `UNIQUE`, and (2) orders the data by `(a,b)`.

`INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` (whether generated by `FOREIGN KEY` or generated manually) is *not* the same as `INDEX(a,b)`.

InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY`, so you may as well say `PRIMARY KEY (a,b)` *instead of* `UNIQUE(a,b)`.

Comment: Why this method  is  better?

Comment: @Webdev - Which of the "Notes" would you like me to elaborate on?

Comment: why composite primary key is better in designing than unique multiple foreign key group_id and permission_id

Comment: @Webdev - I added some more points.  (I don't know if they answer your concern.)